# What's the spider situation in El Salvador?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, central-america, el-salvador

I am considering traveling to El Salvador.  However, I am fearful of spiders.

I am worried about the possibility of finding a disgusting, huge spider in my bed or just seeing it anywhere. El Salvador is located in Central America, and appears to be pretty exotic/hot. This makes me nervous to say the least.

Are there big spiders there? If so, are they located exclusively in the remote jungle, or also where people live?

(I am not looking for advice on getting over this fear.)

Comment: El Salvador will have big spiders, do not move there.

Comment: K Vecchio - If you must ask such a question, your final 3 paragraphs could make an acceptable question on Outdoors Stack Exchange. But as Willeke says - hot countries generally have big spiders. If you dislike spiders move to a colder country.

Comment: In Guadalajara, Mexico (Elevation: 1,566 m) is within the tropical zone, but due the height much dryer than the coastal regions. The spiders (and other bugs) there were **very** large and avoided direct sunlight whenever possible. You often saw them on the ceilings. Beds are often high and the coverings should never reach the floor to insure that scorpions don't make themselves comfortable in the bed. Scorpions are actually very shy, but don't like to be surprised (always turn the light on before getting out of the bed when dark). They also like slippers...

Comment: Whoever designed the figure (and noise they make when scrambling away) of the [Replicators of the Stargate](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Replicator) series had experienced what you see and hear when turning the light on in a bedroom with tiled floors. Literally hundreds of scorpions scrambling away to the nearest dark area with the same noise effect.

Comment: Where are you planning on staying? Big City? Small town? Rural area? Tent in the jungle?

Comment: I would echo "where are you staying?". I live in Australia and we've certainly got our share of big, poisonous spiders. However, since I live in suburbia, I rarely encounter them.

Comment: Luxury hotels are not known to host huge spiders. You should be safe there.

Answer (score -1):

I live here in El Salvador, and i never seen huge spiders,
.

Comment: It would help to know where you lived. In a big city? A rural area?